# How to get the object properties from a list of objects in my model class so that I can pass the objects through intents?

Tags: java, android, xmlpullparser

I successfully parsed and retrieved all the data that I need from an xml document. I have two activities, one activity that shows the main data and other activity that shows an extra data for the recyclerView clicked item. I ma trying to pass all the data needed in the detail activity through intents from the main activity. But I am missing a method in my model class that helps me retrieve the objects themselves from the list to be able to send them into the putExtra(). So what should the method look like? 
** The logcat is giving me this error in the detail activity: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference".

HERE is my MainAactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdsAdapterOnClickHandler {
public static final String URL = "MYURL;
public static List<AdEntry> entryList = new ArrayList<>();
 // Declaration



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Setting the recyclerView and the adapter
    loadPage();

}


public void loadPage() {
    new DownloadXmlTask().execute(URL);
    System.out.print("Result" + "Succeed");
}


private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<AdEntry>> {
    @Override
    protected List<AdEntry> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<AdEntry> adEntries) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Processed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mAdsAdapter.setAdData(adEntries);
        super.onPostExecute(adEntries);
    }
}

public List<AdEntry> loadXmlFromNetwork(String urlString) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = downloadUrl(urlString);
        entryList = parse(stream);
    } finally {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.close();
    }
    return entryList;
}

public InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    // Open HttpURLConnection   
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    final AdEntry entry = entryList.get(position);
    Class destinationClass = DetailActivity.class;
    Intent intentToStartDetailActivity = new Intent(this, destinationClass);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product Name", entry.productName);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product Thumbnail", entry.productThumbnail);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product Description", entry.productDescription);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product AppId", entry.appId);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product CallToAction", entry.callToAction);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product Link", entry.proxyLink);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product ImageRating", entry.averageRatingImageURL);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product Category", entry.productCategory);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product Rating", entry.productRating);
    intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("Product NumberOfRating", entry.numberOfRatings);
    startActivity(intentToStartDetailActivity);

}
```

}

Here is my DetailActivity:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Views Declaration

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    // findViewsById

    retrieveData();


}

public void retrieveData() {
    String productName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Product Name");
    String productThumbnail = getIntent().getStringExtra("Product Thumbnail");
    String productDescription = getIntent().getStringExtra("Product Description");
    String productAppId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Product AppId");
    String productCall = getIntent().getStringExtra("Product CallToAction");
    String productLink = getIntent().getStringExtra("Product Link");
    String productImageRating = getIntent().getStringExtra("Product ImageRating");
    String productCategory = getIntent().getStringExtra("Product Category");
    String productNumberOfRatings = getIntent().getStringExtra("Product NumberOfRating");
    Picasso.get().load(productThumbnail).into(thumbnail_imageView);
    name_textView.setText(productName);
    description_textView.setText(productDescription);
    numberOfRating_textView.setText(productNumberOfRatings);
    link_textView.setText(productLink);
    category_textView.setText(productCategory);
    rating_textView.setText(productImageRating);

}
```

}

Here is my ModelClass:

```
public class AdEntry {
private List<AdEntry> entries;

public String appId;
public String averageRatingImageURL;
public String callToAction;
public String productCategory;
public String proxyLink;
public String productDescription;
public String numberOfRatings;
public String productName;
public String productThumbnail;
public String productRating;

public AdEntry() {
}

public AdEntry(String appId, String averageRatingImageURL, String callToAction, String productCategory, String proxyLink,
               String productDescription, String numberOfRatings, String productName, String productThumbnail, String productRating) {
    this.appId = appId;
    this.averageRatingImageURL = averageRatingImageURL;
    this.callToAction = callToAction;
    this.productCategory = productCategory;
    this.proxyLink = proxyLink;
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
    this.numberOfRatings = numberOfRatings;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productThumbnail = productThumbnail;
    this.productRating = productRating;
}

public String getAppId() {
    return appId;
}

public String getAverageRatingImageURL() {
    return averageRatingImageURL;
}

public String getCallToAction() {
    return callToAction;
}

public String getProductCategory() {
    return productCategory;
}

public String getProxyLink() {
    return proxyLink;
}

public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}

public String getNumberOfRatings() {
    return numberOfRatings;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public String getProductThumbnail() {
    return productThumbnail;
}

public String getProductRating() {
    return productRating;
}
```

}

Here is the part where I retrieved my List in the XMLPUllParser class:

```
private static List readAds(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List<AdEntry> entries = new ArrayList();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "ads");

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            continue;

        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("ad"))
            entries.add(readEntry(parser));
        else
            skip(parser);
    }

    System.out.println("entries" + entries);
    return entries;
}


private static AdEntry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "ad");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            continue;

        String name = parser.getName();
        switch (name) {
            case "appId":
                appId = readAppId(parser);
                System.out.println("appId" + appId);
                break;
            case "averageRatingImageURL":
                averageRatingImageURL = readRatingImage(parser);
                System.out.println("rating" + averageRatingImageURL);
                break;
            case "callToAction":
                callToAction = readCallToAction(parser);
                System.out.println("callToAction" + callToAction);
                break;
            case "categoryName":
                categoryName = readCategoryName(parser);
                System.out.println("categoryName" + categoryName);
                break;
            case "clickProxyURL":
                clickProxyURL = readProxyLink(parser);
                System.out.println("clickProxyURL" + clickProxyURL);
                break;
            case "productDescription":
                productDescription = readProductDescription(parser);
                System.out.println("productDescription" + productDescription);
                break;
            case "numberOfRatings":
                numberOfRatings = readNumberOfRatings(parser);
                System.out.println("numberOfRatings" + numberOfRatings);
                break;
            case "productName":
                productName = readNameProduct(parser);
                System.out.println("productName" + productName);
                break;
            case "productThumbnail":
                productThumbnail = readThumbnail(parser);
                System.out.println("productThumbnail" + productThumbnail);
                break;
            case "rating":
                rating = readRating(parser);
                System.out.println("rating" + rating);
                break;
            default:
                skip(parser);
                break;
        }
    }
    return new AdEntry(appId, averageRatingImageURL, callToAction, categoryName, clickProxyURL, productDescription,
            numberOfRatings, productName, productThumbnail, rating);
}
```

Comment: the `TextView` is `null` - as per the error message.  I can't comment on the bundle data being null or not, maybe print that out in the logcat in the `DetailsActivity` after values retrieved from the `Intent` before you attempt to use widgets with the `String` data?

Comment: Yes it is null because I am not extracting the properties of the object from the list of objects so that I can pass them through intents. My question is that how can I do that?

Comment: "Yes it is null because I am not extracting the properties of the object from the list" - how do you know the extras are null (I already suggested logging these out in `DetailsActivity`)? it is perfectly valid to do `TextView.setText(null);` - this will not throw an error if the `TextView` is not null - I'm only telling you what the error states.  Check your view id's are correct to the content view. Also consider creating a `Parcelable` object rather than adding indiviudal `String` extras.

Comment: replace this line `mAdsAdapter.setAdData(adEntries);` in `onPostExecute(List<AdEntry> adEntries)` with `entryList = adEntries; mAdsAdapter.setAdData(entryList);` - surely the data should match? Also making `entryList` static is not a good idea, it should be an instance variable.